# iOS 13 UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout infinite number of items in group

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

From what I understand each `NSCollectionLayoutGroup` is rendered by the order given to its parent group and each group can also decide how many items are rendered of the its type per group by using `open class func vertical(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize, subitem: NSCollectionLayoutItem, count: Int) -> Self`. On that note, I was wondering if it was possible to render an infinite number of a items (`NSCollectionLayoutItem`) after all previous items have been rendered.

**Desired Layout**

```
---------- <- 1 item
|    |     <- 2 items
---------- <- infinite item
----------
----------
----------
```

The code below current only displays `defaultSection` once despite a count not being given

```
private func createLayout2() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnv) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                    heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
                )
            )
            item.contentInsets = .init(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)

            // Featured
            let bigSection = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(400)
                ),
                subitem: item, count: 1
            )

            // Two tiles
            let tileSecton = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(200)
                ),
                subitem: item, count: 2
            )

            // Default items in list
            let defaultSection = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(200)
                ),
                subitems: [item]
            )

            // Section
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
                ),
                subitems: [bigSection, tileSecton, defaultSection]
            )

            return NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        }
        return layout
    }
```

Comment: Ever found a solution?

Comment: if I remember correctly, I needed up recreating the layout when the items count was changed, wasn't the best solution but only way I could come up with

Comment: Hm, do you have an example? Not sure If I follow :)